# feature not supported: key figure can't be defined without aggregation error in SAP HANA

Tags: sql, hana

When I click on data preview after activating the calculation view in SAP HANA the following error is generated:

> SAP DBTech JDBC: [7]: feature not supported: key figure can't be defined without aggregation

When I opened the SQL editor the final query is:

```
SELECT 
     "PRODUCT_LINE_ID", "PRODUCT_LINE_DESC", "YEAR"
      , sum("Precentage_Growth") AS "Precentage_Growth"
      , max("NET_SALES_REVENUE") AS "NET_SALES_REVENUE"
      , sum("PLANNED_REVENUE") AS "PLANNED_REVENUE" 
FROM 
     "_SYS_BIC"."GBI_077.B17/ACTUALREVENUE_VS_PLANREVENUE_CV_077" 
GROUP BY 
      "PRODUCT_LINE_ID", "PRODUCT_LINE_DESC", "YEAR";
```

where `percentage_growth`, `net_sales_revenue` and `Planned_revenue` are key figures. Can somebody help me on this as I still a beginner in SAP HANA.

Answer (score 0):

This error is most likely due to how the keyfigures have been defined in the `semantics` node of the calculation view.
For every keyfigure defined there, an aggregation mode needs to be set.